# Error messages concatenated in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a form in which I want to clear my error message once it is displayed so that the other message appears. I have an errMsg on the top of my jsp which is always displayed along with the message I want to display. My validator is as follows:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("unixFileName", function(value, element){
        return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_./#-]+$/.test(value);
    });
 $.validator.addMethod("numericOnly", function(value, element){
        return /^[0-9]+$/.test(value);
    });
    var container = $('div.errMsg');
    $("#outputFileSplitForm").validate({
        errorContainer : container,
        errorLabelContainer: container,
        rules:{
            fileName:{unixFileName: true},
            groups:{numericOnly: true},
            recordsPerFile:{numericOnly: true}
        },
        messages:{
            fileName:{unixFileName: "Please enter valid Unix file path"},
            groups:{numericOnly: "Please enter a numeric value"},
            recordsPerFile:{numericOnly: "Please enter a numeric value"}
        }
    });
```

When I try to enter anything other than number in groups, it displays the message "Pleae enter a numeric value" but when I click on the other recordsPerFile it concatenates the message "Please enter a numeric value Please enter a numeric value". I want to see only one message at a time.
I tried using validator.resetForm(). It doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: I don't see java or spring in this scenario, removed those tags